# What does this icon mean in WebStorm autocomplete?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, code-completion

This icon appears when type inference work in autocompletion:

[image: Icon in autocomlete with TypeScript]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[jetbrains.design](https://jetbrains.design/intellij/resources/icons_list/)
here it is labeled as `multipleTypeDefinitions`.

Comment: they changed it now to `dynamicUsages`